# jQuery - Remove Next, Prev Buttons from Slider

Tags: jquery, slider

I tried searching for this, but I had trouble finding something directly related. I am new to jQuery/Javascript so any help would be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

I have a custom slider functionally working with 3 slides in it, and I am using jQuery to toggle back and forth between the slides. Each slide is 1040px wide. Each slide is relatively positioned, and is floating left.

I would like to hide my "button-right" when my slider is at the beginning (so you don't scroll to an empty area), and hide my "button-left" when my slider is at the end (again, so you don't scroll into an empty area).

What logic can I use to do this?

```
$(function(){
$(".button-right").click(function() {
    $(".portfolioSection").animate({left: "-=1040" }, "slow");
}); });

$(function(){
$(".button-left").click(function() {
    $(".portfolioSection").animate({left: "+=1040" }, "slow");
}); });
```

Here is the HTML

```
<div class="portfolioImg" style="background-image: url(images/featured-flushed.jpg);">
    <div class="portfolioImgOver">
        <div class="button-right">Next</div>
        <div class="button-left">Back</div>
        <div class="portfolioSection">
            <div class="finley"></div>
            <div class="portfolioContent">
                <h2>Flushed</h2><br/><br/>Flushed was a project planned for release on mobile platforms.<br /><br />My responsibilities for Flushed included: establishing a visual direction for the game, creating stylized 3D models, and developing technical game art, including textures, user interfaces and sprite sheets.<br /><br />I also worked with another artist to guide and assist with creating concept art, story mechanics and level designs.<br /><br /><span style="font-size:10px; color:#aaa;">Flushed is owned by Applied Studios, LLC.</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolioSection">
            <div class="portfolioContent">
                <h2>WHOA! Another div</h2><br/><br/>Here is some crazy cool stuff that I bet you thought you would never see.
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="portfolioSection">
            <div class="portfolioContent">
                <h2>WHOA! Another div</h2><br/><br/>Here is some crazy cool stuff that I bet you thought you would never see. 
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clear"></div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
<style>.portfolioImg {width:1040px; height:600px; background-color:#efefef; margin-bottom:150px; z-index:1; overflow:hidden;}.portfolioImgOver{width:2080px; height:600px; background: rgba(25,25,25,.94);margin-bottom:150px; display:none; z-index:2; left:0px; position:relative;}.portfolioSection{width:1040px; height:600px; position:relative; float:left;}.portfolioContent{width:300px; color:#dedede; padding:40px; float:left; line-height:22px;}.portfolioContent a{color:#dedede; border-bottom:dotted 1px #888; padding-bottom:1px; text-decoration:none;}.button-right {width:60px; background:#333; color:#fff; padding:10px; position:absolute; z-index:3; right:1040px; top:300px; cursor:pointer; transition: all 0.6s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;}.button-right:hover {background:#777; transition: all 0.6s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;}.button-left {width:60px; background:#333; color:#fff; padding:10px; position:absolute; z-index:3; left:0px; top:300px; cursor:pointer; transition: all 0.6s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;}.button-left:hover {background:#777; transition: all 0.6s ease 0s; -webkit-transition: all 0.6s ease 0s;}</style>
```

Here is a link to the page:

http://alanvitek.com/dev

Comment: can you share the html also

Comment: @ArunPJohny I have included the code and a link to the website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
jQuery(function($){
    var sec = $('.portfolioSection'), secwidth = sec.width(), unit = 1040;

    $(".button-right").click(function() {
        var left = sec.css('left');
        left = Math.abs(parseInt(left.substring(0, left.length - 2)))
        if(left + unit >= secwidth){
            $(this).hide()
        }

        sec.animate({left: "-=" + unit }, "slow");
        $(".button-left").show();
    });


    $(".button-left").click(function() {
        var left = sec.css('left');
        if(left == '-' + unit + 'px'){
            $(this).hide()
        }
        sec.animate({left: "+=" + unit }, "slow");
        $(".button-right").show();
    });
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PpGLJ/)

Comment: Thank you! This is definitely on the right track. I'm going to plug in the values and get it working. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Try to set a variable for your slides (may be in an array), then check if it is the first one, hide the left button. if it is the last, hide the right button.

```
$('.button-left').hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

Set an variable with the status. 1 is the first slide, 2 the second and so on. On every key press add 1 or subtract 1. After that, you can do following:

```
if(variable == 1)$('.button-left').hide()
```